# How to extra values to attributes in material-ui button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-ui buttons API. There are 3 different sizes defined for button namely small, medium and large. Is it possible to add extra sizes into this list? I want this value to appear in VS code's auto-complete menu, hence using withStyles won't help much.  Or is it possible to add more variants which can directly be used by the team without having a need to add custom css classes for every instance? I tried below code by reading one of the article but that doesn't work.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
   overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      variant : {
         name: 'extra-large',
         height: '
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Good question, I found a related issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15573

Comment: And default theme do contain `primary` but not `variant` https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/

Comment: Confirmed, the typescript support is still under progress, however, you can still use it without type check in a way provided in the issue above.

Comment: @keikai, yes, that helps. I hope that feature with typescript will be soon in release.